# Excel User Form, Locate Cell and Insert Date

Tags: excel, vba, search, userform

I have a user form that I want to use to locate a particular cell based on what is entered on the userform.  Once the cell is found, I need to insert a date into a corresponding cell on the same row (different column) as the aforementioned cell that needs to be located.

Here is the code I have, but it doesn't seem to locate any particular cell, and instead just inserts a date in column E at what seems to be a random row.

```
Private Sub InsertRecordButton_Click()
Dim Found As Range
If Me.CloseDate.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Date is set", , "Missing Entry"
Else
    Set Found = 
Sheets("Colonies").Range("E:E").Find(What:=Me.Colonyid.Value, _
                                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext,_
                                                   MatchCase:=True)
    If Found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No match for " & Me.Colonyid.Value, , "No Match Found"
    Else
        Found.Offset(3).Value = Me.CloseDate.Value
    End If
```

Per the code, I am trying to locate what is entered on the userform in Colonyid.Value.  Once located in the workbook, I need to enter CloseDate.Value (automatically populated with today's date) into column E on the same row as the Colonyid.Value.

I can work with a generic example, but I prefer to use my code as a starting block, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim this As String

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rcell As Range

    If ISnUll(Me.TextBox1.Value) = False Then
         this = Me.TextBox1.Value
    ElseIf ISnUll(Me.TextBox1.Value) = true Then
         MsgBox "Input is required for operation. Please enter a value"
         Exit Sub
    End if

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E:E")
    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
    If rcell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        If rcell.Value = this Then
            rcell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Now()
        End If
    End If
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing.  I'm running into an error when I plug in your code using my own textbox control (instead of TextBox1).  

I receive the error: "Invalid use of Null" and it highlights: 

`this = Me.Colonyid.Value`

Comment: Just wrap that in the IsNull function. Like IF IsNull(Me.TextBox1.Value) = False then....

Comment: Good suggestion.  Perhaps though I need this in context:

`this = IsNull(Me.Colonyid.Value) = False` is acceptable in terms of eliminating the null error, but where does the `If` fit? I'm getting compilation errors.

Comment: @JaredBownds check my edit. This is actually a valuable lesson has error handling should always be accounted for as well as data validation.

Comment: makes sense, and agreed, I'm building my toolbox of best practices.  Interesting fact, when running the edited code I'm receiving the MsgBox feedback, although I have something 'selected' or entered in the Colonyid field on the UserForm.  I should mention, this Colonyid is a combo box and is populated like this:
`Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Colonyid.List = Worksheets("Colonies").Range("B2:B500").Value`

So you can see it's a list of values that can be selected.  I'm curious what needs to change to make this work with a combo box.

Comment: @JaredBownds check my edit. Might have been a mistype on my end. Def check SO's documentatio on vba for best practices. I prolly have a decent short list if i could be bothered to type them up LOL

Comment: That works!  oddly though, this code will not play nicely with a combo box. Even with a value selected in the combobox it is still considered null. I had to switch over to a textbox.